# Spring Cloud Bus with aws-kinesis

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-bus

In the documentation of `Spring Cloud Bus` (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-bus) it was mentioned like

> The Bus starters cover **Rabbit** and **Kafka**, because those are the two
>   most common implementations, but Spring Cloud Stream is quite flexible
>   and binder will work combined with spring-cloud-bus.

In my project we can not maintain an another infrastructure for Rabbit or Kafka hence I want to use `spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis` (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis) with `spring-cloud-bus`. Can anyone guide me how can I do that??

Comment: include spring-cloud-bus and the aws kinesis binder, have you tried that?

Comment: @spencergibb That is what I want to do, but I am not sure how to include spring-cloud-bus and the AWS kinesis binder.  Is there any guide or documentation to customize spring cloud bus with any other spring cloud stream implementation like this??

Comment: See my answer...

Comment: Let me try that @ArtemBilan..thanks

Comment: @ArtemBilan, when the stable release of "spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis" will be available ??

Comment: Somewhere the next year. We are not going to release until stable Spring Cloud AWS 2.0 and Spring Cloud Stream 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-bus/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp/pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-bus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I guess the same way we can follow for Kinesis Binder:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-bus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Yes, you need `spring-cloud-bus` and a binder.